# req.body and req.file always return empty in multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multipartform-data, multer, body-parser

I'm following this [Academind Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srPXMt1Q0nY&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q&index=10) for creating a node API endpoint for uploading images where I use `body-parser`  for parsing `json` request and `multer` for parsing `multipart/form-data` request but every time I hit API using postman I get empty `req.body` and `req.file` too.

**This is multer implementation looks like**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/check-auth');
const _ = require('lodash');
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')

    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.filename);
    },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    //reject a file
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype == 'image/png')
        cb(null, true);
    else cb(null, false);

}
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

// update profile image
router.post("/update_profile_image", upload.single('image'),  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.client_id)
    res.send("Done")

});

module.exports = router;
```

and **This is my `app.js` file implementation**

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Thanks in advance